# Eclipse, recover recent history

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to look back into the recent local history saves of an Eclipse project?

What I mean is that:

1: `I Code Something`

I save and run.
I press Ctrl+z...

2: `I Code Something else`

I save and run. I'm not satisfied with the new code, now I want to go back to the initial code.

Is there any way for me to recover what I coded in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Eclipse's [Local History](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm) to achieve what you want by invoking **Team > Show History** on a particular file from Package/Project Explorer or by clicking directly on an opened editor.

[image: Local history]

Answer (score -2):

No.  Eclipse does not (by default) preserve this information.

I can think of two solutions to your problem:

1. Use a version control system, and check in your project on every save.
2. Use a filesystem with file versioning support (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system for more details).